# Alternate BlackBerry Eclipse update site

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, configure

Can somebody tell me how to configure eclipse for Blackberry so that phonegap applications can work properly? I tried following "[Getting Started with PhoneGap BlackBerry WebWorks](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-%28BlackBerry-Widgets%29)"
 but I am not able to configure because the BlackBerry eclipse update site is not available right now. It will be very helpful if somebody give me any alternate link or guide me to configure eclipse for the same.

This is the update URL I am using:
`http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/web`

Answer (score 2):

The bottom of that PhoneGap Wiki article links to [RIM's BlackBerry WebWorks Plug-in page](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/browserdev/eclipseplugin.jsp).

Comment: yes, I checked that too but this again link to the following link http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/web which doesn't work

Comment: Really, after filling out the contact form it sends you to a dead link?  I would definitely contact RIM about that directly.